# Head bolt sequence for 4.3 liter 1995 Chevy 1500

Tags: chevrolet, bolts, cylinder-head, torque-specification

What is the head bolt sequence for a 1995 Chevy truck 4.3 liter engine?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

Torque: Ft Lbs.
1) 25
2) 44
3) 66

[image]